# Fancybox doesnt completely load on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a fancy box that opens up and inside that is a link to trigger another fancy box image gallery where I pass in an array of images.

When you click the trigger on the first visit, it loads only the first image and does not let you cycle through the others.

Strangely when you click the link again it is all fine??

What am I missing here? It is clearly loading part because the first image appears however no controls to cycle are present.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gallery').bind('click', function () {
        $.fancybox(['imgURL', 'imgURL2', 'imgURL3'], {
            'padding': 0,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'image',
            'changeFade': 0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have just discovered that the next and previous buttons do not load straight away the first time.

Comment: it's going to be very difficult to tell what you are missing here without any code to check, don't you think?

Comment: Right, fair enough. Amended the post. I am not a regular user as you can probably tell.